# ILDasm Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ildasm

Is there a convenient method or tool available which will do the following for me from within visual studio 2010.

Fire up ILDasm
Load a current assembly from within Visual Studio within ILDasm.

As opposed to me firing up a visual studio command prompt
Fire up Ildasm
navigating to the bin folder of the assembly I wish to view.

If there isn't something available to do this are there any tools out there which would help?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) can be plugged into Visual Studio. Also it supports multiple languages, not only IL.

Update: [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/) 6 also supports built in decompiler.

Comment: Can I view the CIL using reflector? My understanding is it shows you the source C# code or language specific code?

Comment: Ahh found it in the dropdown in reflector. Cheers for that!

Comment: Going to go with this as the answer. Was not aware of the built in ILDasm disassembler. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this using Tools>External Tools. Setup the necessary parameters for ILDasm.

A brief tutorial may be found [here](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/61/posts/11246/vs2010-tip-how-to-launch-ildasm-from-vs2010-ide.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can get a copy of [TestDriven.Net](http://www.testdriven.net) which will provide that sort of dialog for opening up Reflector.

If you really need ILDasm (and yes, there are good reasons for that too) from the context menu I guess you'll need to write that yourself.

Comment: Looks like Reflector Pro does the same integration (not sure when they did it or whether its restricted to the Pro Ed)

Comment: @Ruben: Looks like they have it in the free ed too http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/features.htm. Now it gets messy, TD.NET does Reflector integration, NDepend does it and Reflector itself. Which one am I using? Hell I don't know :-)